# How to get "user" access token in a Web API using Facebook C# SDK?

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-graph-api, asp.net-web-api

I am developing a web API to handle realtime updates (Lead information) from Facebook to integrate with my CRM.
In the WEB API POST request, I am able to capture the leadID but the problem comes when I get leadinfo by invoking `FB.Get(LeadID)`. To make a Graph API GET request(for lead information) I need to have a user access token and this is where i have been struggling for quite sometime. I have looked up several posts online but havent got any solution for my problem.

In my sample implementation, `GetLoginUrl(parameters)` returns a uri and when  when I request the uri in a browser, I see that the access token gets generated in the redirected Uri. But how to do this programatically ? I have tried the following

string FBAccessUrl = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=XXXXXXXXXXXX&response_type=token&redirect_uri=https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html";
var accessTokenRequest = System.Net.HttpWebRequest.Create(FBAccessUrl);
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)accessTokenRequest.GetResponse();

but then i get this ResponseUri = {https://www.facebook.com/unsupportedbrowser} which is not what I want.

Can someone help me with how the user access token can be generated using C# in the Web API (without the facebook login dialog)

```
[HttpPost]
[ActionName("Complex")]
public void PostComplex(RootObject root)
{
    FacebookClient fb = new FacebookClient();

    // Get leadID from the inital HTTP POST request 
    long leadgen_id = root.entry[0].changes[0].value.leadgen_id;
    string leadID = leadgen_id.ToString();

    // to get user access token
    dynamic parameters = new ExpandoObject();
    parameters.client_id = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
    parameters.redirect_uri = "https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html";
    parameters.response_type = "token";

    // generate the login url
    Uri uri = fb.GetLoginUrl(parameters);

    // reuest the uri in browser and uri2 is the redirected uri
    Uri uri2 = "****************"
    string accesstoken = "";

    FacebookOAuthResult oauthResult;
    if (fb.TryParseOAuthCallbackUrl(uri, out oauthResult))
    {
        if (oauthResult.IsSuccess)
        {
                accesstoken = oauthResult.AccessToken;
        }
        else
        {
            var errorDescription = oauthResult.ErrorDescription;
            var errorReason = oauthResult.ErrorReason;
        }
    }

    fb.AccessToken = accesstoken;
    string me = fb.Get(leadID).ToString();

    // Then fetch required lead information 

}
```